# how to add different activity for each row in listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I know how to add activity to listview by using intent and you can see in below code that i added back.class to my mainactivity.java with customadapter.java file.
But when i click on each row of listview everytime it open only one activity(back.class). Now i want to add different activity (leg.class, abs.class, chest.class etc) to my mainactivity.java using intent So when you click on each row of listview it will open different activity. I don't know how to do it?

This is my mainactitvity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String[] excercise = {"Back DAY", "Legs DAY", "Abs DAY", "Chest DAY", "Shoulder DAY", "Arms DAY"};
        final int[] imgs = {R.drawable.back, R.drawable.leg, R.drawable.abs, R.drawable.chest, R.drawable.shoulder, R.drawable.arms};
        ListAdapter saruadapter = new customadapter(this, excercise, imgs);
        ListView sarulistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sarelistview);
        sarulistview.setAdapter(saruadapter);

       // Intent intent = new Intent();
       // startService(intent);


        sarulistview.setOnItemClickListener(
                new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                      //  String excercise = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, excercise, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, back.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

This is my customadapter.java file

```
public class customadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private int[] imgs;
    public customadapter(Context context, String[] excercise, int[] imgs) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row, excercise);
        this.imgs = imgs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater saruinflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View coustomView = saruinflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

        String excerciseitem = getItem(position);
        TextView saruview = (TextView) coustomView.findViewById(R.id.sareview);
        ImageView saruimg = (ImageView) coustomView.findViewById(R.id.sareimage);

        saruview.setText(excerciseitem);
        saruimg.setImageResource(imgs[position]);
        return coustomView;
    }
}
```

This is my back.java file

```
public class back extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bacon2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle back = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(back == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Switch Condition and use the Position to Open new Activity.

```
  sarulistview.setOnItemClickListener(
        new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              //  String excercise = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, excercise, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       switch (position) {

        case 0:
            Intent i0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, back.class);
            startActivity(i0);

            break;
        case 1:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, leg.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;
        case 2:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, abs.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case 3:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, chest.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            break;

    }
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set **onItemClick** to your **ListView** you get the postion for the clicked item. So you need to do some type of check according to your need to open a different activity.One possible check can be using **position**.For eg:-

```
     sarulistview.setOnItemClickListener(
            new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //  String excercise = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, excercise, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (position == 1) {
                        Intent i0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, back.class);
                        startActivity(i0);
                    }
                    else if(position == 2){
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, chess.class);
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }else {
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, abc.class);
                        startActivity(i2); 
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

This is just an example approach.The business logic will depend upon your need.

Comment: Switch is better the if else if statement. You can do R & D. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074756/how-to-add-different-activity-for-each-row-in-listview-in-android/38074869#38074869)

Comment: @Avinash8989 A switch statement is not always faster than an if statement. It scales better than a long list of if-else statements as switch can perform a lookup based on all the values. However, for a short condition it won't be any faster and could be slower.

Comment: May be but performance is nearly same for both. Both are good. Thnx for correcting me.